# Поиск по файлу на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, поиск

Допустим, что у меня есть файл с названием/описанием продукции и одностраничный сайт, где присутствует строка "поиск". Пользователь заходит на мою страницу и в строке "поиск" вбивает интерессующую его продукцию. Допустим, он вбил название какого-нибудь бренда одежды, а ему вылезает список моделей данного бренда, которые присутсвуют в файле. Как лучше всего это реализовать? Какой язык использовать для этого? или может быть есть какая-нибудь технология для этого, чтобы не изобретать заново велосипед.

Comment: А в чём затруднения? Если в «файле», то просто ищем введённую строку в содержимом файла да и всё. На любом языке. Вопрос не очень понятен

Comment: @andreymal смысл в том, чтобы пользователь на САЙТЕ вводил строку, после чего запускался поиск. Нужно все это совместить с САЙТОМ, а не с приложением на компьютере.

Comment: Опять же, информации про создание сайтов навалом в интернете. Опять же, на любом языке. Опять же, вопрос по-прежнему непонятен

Comment: И да, поиск по файлу на сайте и в приложении не отличаются вообще ничем. Просто приложение на компьютере будет рисовать результат на окошко, а сайт - отвечать на какой-то HTTP-запрос.